# Can we convert UTC time to 24 hour Format? if yes, then How?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, time, utc

I have two different columns to store date And time. One is saving date and other is Time. Before i did it with local time it was working fine. Now i want to set this time for Arizona So for that i convert my date time to UTC time and the Used **TimeZoneIfo**'s Method **ConvertTime** to get Arizona's Time. 
Now My Problem is I can get date using this but while i am saving Time its coming in 12 hours format i want to convert it to 24 hours. 
My code is

```
DateTime UniversalScheduleDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text).ToUniversalTime();
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(Session["TimeZone"].ToString());
objSchdl.SDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(UniversalScheduleDate, timeZoneInfo);
DateTime UniversalStartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartTime.Text).ToUniversalTime();
objSchdl.Stime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(UniversalStartTime, timeZoneInfo).ToString();
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try convert using the **DateTimeParse along with DateTimeKind.Utc**

Example:

```
DateTime UniversalScheduleDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(
DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text),DateTimeKind.Utc);

string formattedDate = DateTime.UniversalScheduleDate.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
```

Comment: The text before the example is pretty irrelevant here - it's the format string which is putting it into 24 hour format... although you're *also* including the AM/PM designator (odd when it's 24 hour) and you're not specifying a culture, which is also odd for custom format strings. It's not at all clear that the original input is *meant* to represent universal time, either.

Answer (score 4):

You need to separate *time zone* information from *string representation*. They're completely orthogonal concepts.

It sounds like you probably just need to specify the format in the `ToString` call, e.g.

```
ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You should also consider *parsing* with a specfic format as well - and considering which culture you want to use.

Also note that converting local time to universal time can be lossy, due to daylight saving time transitions. The .NET framework makes it relatively painful to handle that nicely, but it's something you should bear in mind.

Finally, note that when you call `ToUniversalTime` that will use the *system local* time zone for conversion - is that really what you want?

Comment: yes i want to convert it to Arizona's Time Zone, I am getting error on CultureInfo what namespeace to be added for it???

Comment: @raman: Did you try looking in the documentation? A search of "msdn CultureInfo" will find it very quickly. I know you want to convert it *to* Arizona's time zone - but what about your initial `ToUniversalTime()` call? That converts it *from* the system time zone...

Comment: thanks i have googled for it.. thanks for helping me.. – raman 1 hour ago

Answer (score 0):

Have your time in 12 hours format. Just before saving it to the DB you can use the below scripts to change to 24 hour format and save it

Hope the below code helps you.

```
        Response.Write("With Seconds" + "<br />");

        Response.Write("24 Hour Date Format : " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt") + "<br />");
        Response.Write("Without Seconds" + "<br />");

        Response.Write("24 Hour Date Format : " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm tt") + "<br />");
```

Comment: CultureInfo namespace  System.Globalization.CultureInfo